# Problem A.4 from An introduction to manifolds by Loring Tu

Tags: general-topology

My problem is the following

> Prove that the open cube $]-a,a[^n$ is contained in the open ball $B(0,a\sqrt{n})$, which in turn is contained in the open cube $]-a\sqrt{n},a\sqrt{n}[^n$. Therefore, open cubes with arbitrary centers in
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$ form a basis for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**My attempt.** I know it's wrong to ask for the resolution of the exercise without an attempt, but in this case I can't start in the resolution, maybe I miss some theoretical tool.

> **Question.** Could you at least tell me what tools to use to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: draw a picture in the plane (that is, $n = 2$) and convince yourself that the stated inclusions hold. If you have this, it should be not so difficult to generalize to higher dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the two-dimensional case, drawing a picture to see what is going on. Then, you can do an induction in $n$ for the general case. Another way is just to fix $n$ and use the definitions of the cube and ball:

If $x\in (-a,a)^n$, then $x=(x_1,\cdots, x_n)$ such that $-a<x_i<a:\ 1\le i\le n$. Then, $\|x\|=\sqrt{x^2_1+\cdots + x^2_n}<\sqrt{a^2+\cdots + a^2}=a\sqrt n\Rightarrow x\in B(0,a\sqrt n).$

I'll leave the second inclusion to you.